# Appium CORS Setting the document.domain on the subframes of the main frame

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to automate switching to a subframe for a webpage. However, when I attempt to switch to the subframe, I get the following error:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://redirectedSiteOfOriginalSite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://originalSite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

The problem is that the main frame's origin has changed because the site was redirected to a newer site of the original site. Is there a way that I can set the document.domain in automation?

I have tried executing the raw javascript on the webdriver but that fails with:

```
Error while executing atom: The operation is insecure. (status: 18)
```

Any ideas how to get around this?